# How to find that $P(X+Y=n)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are integer random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, integer-valued random variables, then for any integer $n$,
\begin{equation*}
P(X+Y=n) = \sum_{m= -\infty}^{\infty} P(X=m) P(Y=n-m)
\end{equation*}

My attempt:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X+Y=n) &=& P\left(\bigcup_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \{X=m, Y= n-m\}\right)\\
&=& \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}P(X=m \cap~Y=n-m)\\
&=& \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} P(X=m). P(Y=n-m)
\end{eqnarray*}

Is this attempt correct?

Comment: Your union is incorrect, because you don’t know $X=0$ is impossible. Nor do you know $X=-1$ is impossible, nor $X=-2,\dots.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for your point. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost correct: every sum (and union) should be the sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Every sum **and** union.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews, thank you, I didn't noticed.